# What is the purpose of this code section?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10
void main()
{
int *ptr, *arr[MAX];
int i, j;
for (i=MAX-1; i>=0; i--)

if (arr[i]=(int*)malloc(i*sizeof(int)))  // <= that line!

for (j=0; j<i; j++)
*(*(arr+i)+j) = j*i;

ptr = *(arr+MAX-1);
while (*ptr)    
printf ("%d ", *ptr--);
}
```

I am not understand what the purpose of this command:

```
arr[i]=(int*)malloc(i*sizeof(int))
```

I know that this malloc dynamic allocation.
But what is meant by arr[i] it gives the sizeof*i ?
Thanks.

Comment: Ehm, I'm assuming you tried to emphasize the if statement in your code? (using ** **) You might want to remove that. Edit: Thanks @NiklasB

Comment: Yikes! Do you realize you have a single statement spanning 6 lines (2 of them empty) of your code? I suggest you break that statement into smaller statements.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix

Comment: Remember to accept correct answers!

Answer (score 2):

The command that you are talking about allocates a block of length that is sufficient to store `i` items of type `int`, and stores the result at the `i`-th position in the array of pointers called `arr`. The program creates a "triangular" `arr` array: its elements are arrays of different lengths, arranged in such an order that `arr[i]` can hold `i` elements.

By the way, this code is missing calls to `free` for the items it has allocated.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *ptr, *arr[MAX]
```

creates a pointer to int and an array with MAX elements of pointers to int.

```
arr[i]=(int*)malloc(i*sizeof(int))
```

Allocates space for `i` ints for every int pointer.

Answer (score 1):

At first `sizeof()` "returns" (it should be replaced with numeric value during compilation) the size of provided type. Means 4 for `int` (8 on 64b machines), 1 for `char` and so on.

Therefore `i*sizeof(int)` means size for i ints (`i = 4; sizeof( int) = 4;` than it's `16`).

`malloc()` uses number of bytes to allocate as parameter, therefore `malloc(16)` allocate 16bytes, enough space for 4 4B integers.

`(int*)` is just something like *C-hack* to have correct types (because you want to use those 16B as `int[4]` not as `void *`).

The whole code means to allocate space for i ints on i-th place of array (1 on first, 2 on second...). However I wander what will happen for 0, when you'll try to allocate 0 Bytes :)

Answer (score 0):

It's allocating increasingly longer arrays as each element of the arr. so arr[0] points to a 0  size array, arr[2] points to an array of 2 ints and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is an array of pointers to `int`. Every element of it - `arr[x]` - is a pointer to `int`, so an array. It's an array of arrays of ints.

For each element of the array, you create an array with size of the current index.

Note though that your code is illegal, since when `i==0`, you will call `malloc(0)`.

Also, it's good practice not to cast the return type of `malloc`.